# .Net Extension Methods vs Utility Classes

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Duplicate of about 20 recent questions; someone please link them.

For simple scenarios when should i use one or the other?  What are the pros & cons?

What are the recommendations for using extension methods?

EDIT:

Let me give an example.  Lets say i have a web relative path represented as a string.  Now i want to write a method which 1) Checks if the path begins with '/en/ or '/fr/' 2) if it does not then take the value to prepend from another string.

e.g Extension Method

```
public static string ToLocaleRelativePath(this string s, string contextPath)
        {
//1. Check if string begins with a locale
//2. If it does not prepend the value extracted from the context path
}
```

Is such an operation suited for an exteniosn method or should it be a utility?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, a utility class is probably more appropriate, because it makes sense only for strings representing relative URLs, rather than for all strings.  By contrast, a method that applied to all (or the huge majority of) strings (say, a Trim or Reverse method (if such things didn't already exist)) would fit nicely as an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good hints that utility classes are bad because they empower and encourage bad practices contradicting OOP patterns (consider [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/nickmalik/archive/2005/09/06/461404.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/elee/archive/2009/05/05/helper-classes-are-evil.aspx)).